# To be followed by adjective/verb

Tags: grammar

Mostly, I have seen that **to be** is followed by **adjective/verb** , whereas In Today's new paper, **it (to be)** is followed by **article as well as noun**, so how is this possible?

> Andhra Pradesh without the revenue flow from Hyderabad (which accounted for 22 per cent of the total revenue of the undivided State) is in dire financial straits as the special status promised by the previous UPA government has proved to be elusive. As an ally of the BJP at the Centre, the Telugu Desam Party that rules Andhra Pradesh is hoping for a special financial grant. But that too appears **to be a distant dream** today as too many States are in the queue seeking such packages

Thanks,

Charmi

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what it is that you don't understand. *To be + adjective/verb* could be "He is happy". *To be + article + noun" could be "He is a (happy) man". Or are you referring strictly to the infinitive, and if so, why should that be any different?

Comment: Yes JMB, I am referring strictly to the infinitive

Answer (score 1):

You're confused as how to separate the sentence in different parts. It's actually *modifying verb + infinite | article+noun*, not *modifying verb | infinite+article+noun*; i.e., *appears to be | a distant dream*, not *appears | to be a distant dream*.

In this sentence, **to be** is used as a *linking verb*. As mentioned in the comments, it is used exactly the same as 'He is a happy man'.

So, the sentence could have read 'But that too **is** a distant dream today ...'. However, then the sentence implies that it *certainly* is a distant dream, although the writer wants to say that it *looks like it is a distant dream.*

So, compare the sentence to *'He **walks** down the street'* and *'He **appears to walk*** down the street. In the same way, the sentence *'But that too **is** a distant dream today'* is modified to *'But that too **appears to be** a distant dream today'*.

Comment: Thank you Sanchises, but in above paragraph, in the sentence (the special status promised by the previous UPA government has proved to be elusive) "to be" used as infinitive verb right… or my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, but again it is a modification of **'is'** to **'proved to be'**. So, the *infinite + article + noun* is not the grammatical construct of interest, but *modifying verb + infinite* is! For example, *'The plane took off from the airport'*, one could ask a question like *'What kind of construct is 'off from'?* whereas the construct in question is 'to take off' and 'from + noun'. So, to conclude, the question isolates part of the sentence that is not a separate construct at all!

Comment: @CharmiSapariya To put it another way: in each of these the first verb in the chain--*prove*, *appear*, *seem*--requires that a clausal complement be headed by a marked infinitive.